# How to add AzureAD AND AzureADBearer to asp.net core 2.2 web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to author a website that uses AzureAD to authenticate users to access UIs to author items in a DB. And I also want this API to be callable by other services via a bearer token.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(o => {
                    o.DefaultScheme = AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme;
                    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

I want users to be authenticated using the AzureAD scheme, but services to the same WEB API (under a dif route) to be authenticated by the bearer. Or have all routes except both. Either works

Answer (score 10):

ended up solving this by creating a policy scheme which toggles between the two schemas depending on the auth header present:

```
// add azure ad user and service authentication
            services
                .AddAuthentication("Azures")
                .AddPolicyScheme("Azures", "Authorize AzureAd or AzureAdBearer", options =>
                {
                    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
                    {
                        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                        if (authHeader?.StartsWith("Bearer") == true)
                        {
                            return AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme;
                        }

                        return AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    };
                })
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => config.Bind("AzureAdBearer", options))
                .AddAzureAD(options => config.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Comment: This has helped. Quick unrelated question, after setting up the ForwardDefaultSelector, in case of non authorization header for api requests want to stop redirection to login page and return 401. any idea how to do that ?

Comment: @Shubhan returning null instead of AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, when authHeader is null, should do the trick.

Comment: What's the new way to do this using Microsoft.Identity.Web?  What do I use instead of the `AddAzureAD` and `AddAzureADBearer` calls?

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `AddAzureADBearer` middleware to your application :

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdBearer", options));
```

Suppose you have api controller in your application , if another application will access the web api which protected by AAD , you should set the schema :

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureADBearer")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: I tend to prefer using forward selectors in the authentication scheme configuration instead of having to specify the schemes every time.

Comment: This doesn't end up working -- creates a redirect loop for one of the authentication scenarios and locks the API down to one schema

Comment: Using this gives me this error::: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Comment: @Sid , do you correct config in the `AddAzureADBearer` options

Comment: What's the new way to do this using Microsoft.Identity.Web?  What do I use instead of the `AddAzureAD` and `AddAzureADBearer` calls?